# Uploading an image to a form using Python Selenium

Tags: forms, file, selenium-webdriver, upload

I am trying to upload an image to a website using Python Selenium WebDriver.

However, the element that I interact with is a `<form>` element that has a bunch of `<div>` elements and `<i>` element inside it but no `<input>` element. When I try `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'xpath/to/form/element'))).send_keys('/path/to/image.jpg')` it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException`. Any idea how to upload my image without the need of a GUI module?

Comment: Do you see any input tag that has an attribute called type and value = file ?

Comment: Provide at least some pieces of HTML  or URL if it's public, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.